# An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll during Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am using VS 2019 Package Manager Console. I've been using this Scaffold-DbContext successfully in the past days. But today, suddenly I got an error and I can't seem to figure it out. Restart didn't work out. Clean/Rebuild didn't help, either.

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MYPC;Database=MyProject;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
Failed to load the dll from [D:\Source\Repos\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\win-x86\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [D:\Source\Repos\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\win-x86\]
```

Comment: I checkout my previous version where I've been doing Scaffold-DbContext successfully. Still the same error. I guess, I have to retry installing side-by-side the latest preview version of VS2019 to rule out my IDE.

Comment: I tried using the latest VS 2019 16.3.0 Preview 1.0 and it works. Don't know yet why my current version is mess up.

Comment: I found the culprit. Always set the project as active where the entities will be created and set the same project in the Package Manager Console. Because my entities reside on a different project, setting my main app as active project and setting the active project in the Package Manager Console to my entities' project causes this error.